# "The resource cannot be found" from ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've generated an action result in a controller that will generate an excel file,  and I'm passing it to a View in a button via @url.Action helper but when I click on the button it says:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please reveiw the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Report/PinpointReport

Controller.cs code

```
public ActionResult PinpointReport(DateTime Period)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Test")
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "test,xlsx");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "An error occurred loading the report: " + ex.Message;

        string errorString = ex.ToString();
        return Json(new
        {
            error = errorString
        });
    }
}
```

Reports.cshtml   code

this is where i'm calling my action result

```
<input type="button" value="View Total Revenue" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("PinpointReport", "Report")'" />

public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{
    var products = new System.Data.DataTable("test");
    products.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
    products.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));

    products.Rows.Add(1, "product 1");
    products.Rows.Add(2, "product 2");
    products.Rows.Add(3, "product 3");
    products.Rows.Add(4, "product 4");
    products.Rows.Add(5, "product 5");
    products.Rows.Add(6, "product 6");
    products.Rows.Add(7, "product 7");


    var grid = new GridView();
    grid.DataSource = products;
    grid.DataBind();

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xlsx");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    grid.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return View("Reports");
}
```

Comment: can u show us the button click code were u r calling PinpointReport in UrlAction

Comment: "Test" is not a valid file path.

Comment: Sorry I thought I put the code - this is where I'm calling the ActionResult:                                 

<input type="button" value="View Total Revenue" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("PinpointReport", "Report")'" />

Answer (score 1):

In your comment you are not passing the DateTime parameter in your action, try this:

```
<input type="button" value="View Total Revenue"onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("PinpointReport", "Report", new { Period = 'some date' })'" />
```

Comment: Thank you all for your replies - I just tried a different approach altogether by using another function I found on the web and this seems to be working although now I'm getting a format error when trying to open the file but at least now I'm opening  a file without redirecting the user anywhere else which is what I originally intended to do.